# Google Analytics V3 Hits on iOS not Received

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I'm Implementing Google Analytics V3.17 in my iOS Project, here is my implementation:

```
var configureError: NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
    assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
}
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true
gai.dispatchInterval = 20
gai.dryRun = false
```

And in my view Controller:

```
self.screenName = "Screen Name"    
let builder:NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker?.send(builder as! [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

I'm Receiving in the console that the hits were sent successfully:

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestPostUrl:payload:compression:](GAIRequestBuilder.m:167): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:633): Sending hit(s) POST: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:530): hit(s) Successfully deleted
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 10 hit(s) sent
```

However, Whenever I go to google analytics I can't find any data received there, I tried real time and normal audience data, I even waited for a week for the data to show up and still nothing shows up.

I tried google analytics sample project and added my own GoogleService-Info.plist file, I received the data instantaneously on my google analytics account with the same tracking ID.

Note: I was implementing Google Analytics V2 before and it was working fine before I removed it. Also, I'm implementing Fabric crashlytics in the same project if this makes any difference.

Anybody have an Idea whats going wrong?

Comment: You solved the issue ?